# Can I access mysqli::get_warnings() when using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

The get_warnings() function on the mysqli connection object returns useful warnings such as `Warning: 1366: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'published'`. These warnings help in building reliable code.

Can I access there warning messages from CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

CI provides `$this->db->error();` which will return an array containing the error code and message. I'm not sure *warnings* show up in this list.

It is possible to execute PHP mysqli function directly. You need to run a CI function that returns a `CI_DB_result`. From there you have access to the member `conn_id` which will can be used as the `mysqli $link` used by many of the procedural methods of PHP's mysqli extension.

```
$query = $this->db->get('some_table');
//$query is of type CI_DB_result
//Use it to run PHP mysqli function directly
$row_count = mysqli_affected_rows($query->conn_id);
```

I've tested this and it works, as does `mysqli_field_count($query->conn_id);`

I would expect `mysqli_get_warnings ($query->conn_id)` to work also.